# Create Server side for mobile app(android)

Tags: android, iphone, sql-server, oauth

I'm trying to create a new android app from scratch and I'm trying to investigate on how to create a server backside that will support the following: oauth and sql.
I'm just a beginner and I don't familiar with building servers side for mobile app.

Is this the right flow to start building server-side for mobile app?

1) buy/register for some backside storage that will contain my code(EX. godaddy).
2) Install there SQL server and auth server(? - :( )
3) Install VS2010 and connect to the server
4) Start coding in PHP and deploy the code when I'm done.

Thank guys

Edit 1:
What do you say guys about http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-django/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at this link:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/06/bootstrap-your-apps-cloud-services-with.html

Google is now offering a whole host of cloud backend stuff pretty much ready to work with mobile devices, and specially extra libraries ready to use on Android.

It's free to begin with and if your app works and start to have a lot traffic, then it starts to have some charges.

Further, it's mostly in Java already, so it's piece of cake for Android developer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at parse.com  They make backends for mobile super easy.  I use them all the time.